# R - change color in a chart and remove one of the variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I have the following code for the img attached. I would like to change the colour code to get green for vegetation, blue for water and purple for arable lands. Moreover, I would like to remove "built up" in green from the legend and make the characters bigger.
Does someone know how to do that?

```
### results

dat <- readxl::read_xlsx(
  "~/Desktop/Thesis_Results/Bérénice_Thesis_results.xlsx"
) |> janitor::clean_names()

dat |>
    mutate(meff = str_replace_all(meff, "not calculated", "NA")) |> 
    mutate(meff = as.numeric(meff)) |> 
    ggplot(aes(year, meff)) +
        geom_col(aes(fill = land_type), position = "dodge") +
        facet_wrap(~place) +
    theme_light(base_size = 6)

ggsave(
    filename = "lcc_graph_example.png",
    plot = last_plot(), width = 6, height = 3, device = "png", dpi = 300
)
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: To change the Colors accordingly, the `scale_fill_manual()` function will be your friend!

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`? So we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also have a look at `theme()` to increase general font size.